# What is the audio buffer size and FFT size for recording audio every 10 ms?

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to record audio using the AudioRecord API, and I'm trying to convert time domain to frequency domain. If I want to record audio every 10 ms than what is the buffer and FFT size ?

```
audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, what is the buffersize?);

short = new short[what is the buffer size ?];
int fftSize = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sample rate is 44.1 kHz then 10 ms will be 0.01 * 44100 = 441 samples.

If your FFT library only supports powers of 2 sizes then you could use N = 512 as your FFT size and either pad with zeroes or use overlapping windows.

Comment: thanks for reply.if fft size 512 then is this correct audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 512 (0r) 2*512);